# Unicode character description escapes

Tags: php, unicode-escapes

I'm revisiting a browser add-on I created quite a while ago which offered conversion to and from various Unicode escape sequences.

However, I have now quite absentmindedly forgotten, and been unable to rediscover, mention of the language where an escape sequence like `\C{Latin Small Letter A}` was supposed to work (a Unicode description being substituted by the actual Unicode character, in this case, "a").

I believe it was in PHP, or perhaps at least a proposal for PHP, but I do not see any specs which support this syntax now.

Comment: It was not PHP.

Comment: The closest thing I could find was with [\p in regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: Is this maybe part of LaTeX?

Comment: No, I'm almost certain it was a proposal to PHP; I seem to recall a slideshow mentioning an upcoming or proposed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can only work with a codepoint

```
$ php -r 'var_dump("\u{2615}");'
string(3) "☕"
```

Python can

```
>>> import unicodedata

>>> print(unicodedata.lookup('Hot Beverage'))
☕
```

You can use a Python script and call it from the PHP